# Why does `cat <(cat)` produce EIO?

Tags: bash, io, stdin, subshell, process-substitution

I have a program that reads from two input files simultaneously. I'd like to have this program read from standard input. I thought I'd use something like this:

```
$program1 <(cat) <($program2)
```

but I've just discovered that

```
cat <(cat)
```

produces

```
....
mmap2(NULL, 139264, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xb758e000
read(0, 0xb758f000, 131072)             = -1 EIO (Input/output error)
....
cat: -: Input/output error
```

and similarly,

```
$ cat <(read -n 1)
bash: read: read error: 0: Input/output error
```

So... Linux is failing to `read` at the syscall level. That's interesting. Is `bash` not wiring stdin to the subshell? :(

Is there a solution to this? I specifically need to use process substitution (the `... <(...)` format) because `$program1` (`tail`, incidentally) expects files, and I need to do some preprocessing (with `od`) on standard input before I can pass it to `tail` - I can't just specify `/dev/stdin` et al.

EDIT:

What I actually want to do is read from a file (which another process will be writing to) while I *also* read from standard input so I can accept commands and such. I was hoping I could do

```
tail -f <(od -An -vtd1 -w1) <(cat fifo)
```

to read from standard input *and* the FIFO simultaneously and drop that into a single stdout stream I could run through awk (or similar). I know I could solve this trivially in any scripting language, but I like learning how to make `bash` do everything :P

EDIT 2: I've asked [a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42859785/how-can-i-select-ie-simultaneously-read-from-standard-input-and-a-file-in) that more fully explains the context I described just above.

Comment: Interesting because it works on OS-X. So not coming from bash as I initially suspected. That's an interesting one.

Comment: @DanielVoina: Thanks for the info, I was very curious about other platforms!

Comment: I don't quite understand your real need as it's a bit weird to `tail` the `stdin`. Hope my answer can give you some hint.

Comment: Seeing questions like this on StackOverflow gives me hope for the programming profession

Comment: @whjm: Very good point. I [fully described the context in a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42859785/how-can-i-select-ie-simultaneously-read-from-standard-input-and-a-file-in), and accepted your answer to this one as it does canonically answer it :)

Comment: @DanielVoina -- The behavior is not OS related. Maybe OSX is using a different (older?) version of bash which deals with pgrps in a different (buggy?) way.

Comment: @whjm: GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin16) is the standard OS-X version

Comment: @DanielVoina -- could you help try `ssh user@host` on your osx as i mentioned in my another answer?

Comment: @whjm: On ssh session the behaviour is also flawed see here: http://pastebin.com/BRQCDV2G

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### 1. Explain why `cat <(cat)` produces `EIO`

( *I'm using Debian Linux 8.7, Bash 4.4.12* )

Let's replace `<(cat)` with the long running `<(sleep)` to see what's happening.

From **pty #1**:

```
$ echo $$
906
$ tty
/dev/pts/14
$ cat <(sleep 12345)
```

Go to another **pty #2**:

```
$ ps t pts/14 j
  PPID    PID   PGID    SID TTY       TPGID STAT   UID   TIME COMMAND
   903    906    906    906 pts/14    29999 Ss       0   0:00 bash
   906  29998    906    906 pts/14    29999 S        0   0:00 bash
 29998  30000    906    906 pts/14    29999 S        0   0:00 sleep 12345
   906  29999  29999    906 pts/14    29999 S+       0   0:00 cat /dev/fd/63
$ ps p 903 j
  PPID    PID   PGID    SID TTY       TPGID STAT   UID   TIME COMMAND
     1    903    903    903 ?            -1 Ss       0   0:07 SCREEN -T linux -U
$
```

Let me explain it (according to the [APUE book](http://www.apuebook.com/), 2nd edition):

1. The `TPGID` being `29999` indicates that `cat` (PID `29999`) is the foreground process group which is now controlling the terminal (`pts/14`). And `sleep` is in the background process group (PGID `906`).
2. The process group of `906` is now an *orphaned process group* because *"the parent of every member is either itself a member of the group or is not a member of the group’s session"*. (The PID `906`'s PPID is `903` and `903` is in a different session.)
3. When the process in an orphaned background process group reads from its controlling terminal, `read()` would fail with `EIO`.

#### 2. Explain why `cat <(cat)` sometimes *works* (not really!)

[Daniel Voina](https://stackoverflow.com/users/400026/) mentioned in a comment that `cat <(cat)` *works* on OS X with Bash `3.2.57`. I just managed to reproduce it also on Linux with Bash `4.4.12`.

From **pty #1**:

```
bash-4.4# echo $$
10732
bash-4.4# tty
/dev/pts/0
bash-4.4# cat <(cat)
cat: -: Input/output error
bash-4.4#
bash-4.4#
bash-4.4# bash --norc --noprofile  # start a new bash
bash-4.4# tac <(cat)
                      <-- It's waiting here so looks like it's working.
```

(The first `cat <(cat)` failing with `EIO` was explained in the first part of my answer.)

Go to another **pty #2**:

```
bash-4.4# ps t pts/0 j
 PPID   PID  PGID   SID TTY      TPGID STAT   UID   TIME COMMAND
10527 10732 10732 10732 pts/0    10805 Ss       0   0:00 bash
10732 10803 10803 10732 pts/0    10805 S        0   0:00 bash --norc --noprofile
10803 10804 10803 10732 pts/0    10805 S        0   0:00 bash --norc --noprofile
10804 10806 10803 10732 pts/0    10805 T        0   0:00 cat
10803 10805 10805 10732 pts/0    10805 S+       0   0:00 tac /dev/fd/63
bash-4.4# ps p 10527 j
 PPID   PID  PGID   SID TTY      TPGID STAT   UID   TIME COMMAND
10526 10527 10527 10527 ?           -1 Ss       0   0:00 SCREEN -T dtterm -U
bash-4.4#
```

Let's see what's happening:

1. The `TPGID` being `10805` indicates that `tac` (PID `10805`) is the foreground process group which is now controlling the terminal (`pts/0`). And `cat` (PID `10806`) is in the background process group (PGID `10803`).
2. But this time the pgrp `10803` is not orphanded because its member PID `10803` (`bash`)'s parent (PID `10732`, `bash`) is in another pgrp (PGID `10732`) and it's in the same session (SID `10732`).
3. According to the [APUE book](http://www.apuebook.com/), `SIGTTIN` will be *"generated by the terminal driver when a process in a (non-orphaned) background process group tries to read from its controlling terminal"*. So when `cat` reads stdin, `SIGTTIN` will be sent to it and by default this signal would **stop** the process. That's why the `cat`'s `STAT` column was shown as `T` (stopped) in the `ps` output. Since it's stopped the data we input from keyboard are not sent to it at all. So it just **looks like** it's working but it's not really.

#### Conclusion:

So the different behaviors (`EIO` vs. `SIGTTIN`) depend on whether the current Bash is a session leader or not. (In the 1st part of my answer, the bash of PID `906` is the session leader, but the bash of PID `10803` in the 2nd part is not the session leader.)

Comment: Why does this happen? What is 903 and in what session do we find it?

Comment: Added info about `903`. But here all we need to know is it's in a different session.

Comment: **a)** Headsmash; now I have to figure out a second approach. **b)** Thankyou so much for this amazing information :) (PS: GNU sleep accepts undocumented `infinity` parameter.)

Comment: I never know that. Not as easy as inputting a big number. :)

Comment: Silly question but, why can't we use /dev/stdin and combine it with a pipe? Something like `some_filtering_cmd | real_cmd /dev/stdin <(other_cmd) | tail` etc.

Comment: @whjm: Very true! `sleep 12345` and `sleep 9d` are less keystrokes :)

Comment: @LeoIzen: I asked [a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42859785/how-can-i-select-ie-simultaneously-read-from-standard-input-and-a-file-in) with full context and details, FYI

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer explained why, but I saw one solution which can solve it. It is by subshelling it with additional `()`, such as:

`(cat <(cat))`

Please find the solution details here:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/244333/89706

Comment: Thanks for the cross-link. I of course would never have found that question.