# How can I select() (ie, simultaneously read from) standard input *and* a file in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, select, stdin

I have a program that accepts input on one FIFO and emits output to another FIFO. I want to write a small script to control this program. The script needs to listen both to standard input (so I can input commands to adjust things in real time) *and* the program's output FIFO (so it can respond to events happening there as well).

Essentially my control program needs to `select` between standard input and a file (my FIFO).

I like learning how to figure out how to develop simple and elegant `bash`-based solutions to complex problems, and after a little headscratching I remembered that that `tail -f` will happily `select` on multiple files and tell you when one of them changes in real time, so I initially tried

```
tail -f <(od -An -vtd1 -w1) <(cat fifo)
```

to read both standard input (I'd previously run `stty icanon min 1`; this `od` invocation shows each stdin character on a separate line alongside its ASCII code, and is great for escape sequence parsing) and my FIFO. This failed epically (as does `cat <(cat)`): `od` gets run here as a backgrounded task, so it doesn't get access to the controlling TTY, and fails with a cryptic "I/O error" [that was explained incredibly well here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42851792/3229684).

So now I'm a bit stumped. **I realize that I can use any scripting language** like Perl/Python/Ruby/Tcl to solve this; my compsci/engineering question is whether/how I might be able to solve this using (Linux) shell scripting.